# Matlab Finding Unique Permutations

Tags: matlab, unique, permutation

How would I modify the code to just get only the unique values of the permutations?

```
x = -1:1; 
a = 1:length(x);
[a1,a2] = ndgrid(a); 
y = x([a2(:) a1(:)]);

   y        unique y
-1  -1      -1  -1
-1   0      -1   0
-1   1      -1   1
0   -1       0   0
0    0       0   1
0    1       1   1
1   -1          
1    0          
1    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straighforward approach is probably to sort each pair of values first and then apply [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html):

```
unique_y = unique(sort(y, 2), 'rows');
```

If the order of values in the original pairs is important, and you want to make sure that `sort` does not introduce "new" pairs, you can alter the solution as follows:

```
unique_y = unique(intersect(y, sort(y, 2), 'rows'), 'rows');
```